# Duplicating a object; glitch; Axis

Tags: mesh, axis

just starting out on blender and had a small issue when trying to duplicate/move a linked object. So Im trying to duplicate/move a cylinder mesh, but every time i try to duplicate it (Shift + D) to another location, only the axis of that object seems to be moving. Im pretty sure its the axis as the "duplicated" mesh remains in the same location as the parent object, know that because when I delete one cylinder theres a duplicate behind it.

Again, I select the parent mesh > run the duplicate command > move my cursor. The only thing that seems to be moving is the XZY Axis, not the actual object.

What Im doing wrong here; Spent a couple of hours trying to find a solution, no success[image]. Would appreciate an answer.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have activated "affect only: origins" from the tool menu:

[image: Affect]

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Cheers!